# NAA flag declined, but the answer was edited significantly between my flag and the handling

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1056964/380318) as not an answer at 18:55 UTC. If you look at the current state of the answer, you would think it makes perfect sense that the flag was declined:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

However, the answer [was edited](https://superuser.com/posts/1056964/revisions) at 18:58 UTC after I commented. [Its original form](https://superuser.com/revisions/1056964/1) was very much not an answer.

I was under the impression that NAA flags are automatically marked helpful if the answer is edited by its author. Is that system broken, or am I mistaken about how this stuff works?

Comment: I thought that VLQ flags were handled in this way, but I'm not sure about NAA flags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the timeline, I see that the answer was already cleaned up by the time the NAA was processed by a Mod(not me, fwiw) and hence declined.

NAA flags are not auto processed(to my knowledge) - VLQ flags, however, are auto declined when an edit is done

This is the difference between an auto invalidation and Manual clearance:

[image: auto invalidation]

[image: Manual clearance]

Comment: "VLQ flags... are auto declined when an edit is done"? Is that really true? I would think it makes more sense for them to be automatically marked helpful, or at the worst disputed, if the edit is made by the original poster (or really anybody but the flagger).

Comment: @BenN VLQ is for those posts which are supposed to be unsalvageable; _This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed._ if it's edited,  it means it's not unsalvageable :)